# How to bind database record upon successful insert query

Tags: database, cassandra, cql, gocql

`ScanCAS()` & `MapScanCAS()` are returning the values of the database row(old), only if the insert statement is not applied on a database table.

```
insertQuery = "INSERT INTO my_table (id, column1, column2) " + "VALUES (?, ?, toTimeStamp(now())) IF NOT EXISTS"

applied, err := session.Query(insertQuery,ID,column1).ScanCAS(&id,
        &value1,
        &value2)
```

---

How to bind the values of table row, upon successful insert? because `ScanCAS` binds the values(previous) only with failed attempt of insert query....

Comment: but do you have data that you attempted to insert?

Comment: @AlexOtt yes I have that data, except timestamp (third column) generated by database.

Comment: unfortunately this is how Cassandra behaves. Anyway it's usually recommended to generate timestamp on the client side instead of relying on `now()`

Comment: @AlexOtt If client machine sits in different time zone than database machine?

Comment: generate in UTC - cassnadra is doing it anyway